# How to randomize the order of elements of a list while making sure no consecutive values are equal?

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sorting, random

I have a python list of strings, let's say:

```
elems = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
```

I want to create a new list whose elements are each element of `elems` repeated a fixed number of times (let's say twice), in a random order, but while making sure that two consecutive elements never have the same value.

For example, `["D", "B", "A", "B", "D", "C", "A", "C"]` is a good result. `["D", "B", "A", "B", "D", "C", "C", "A"]` is not (C is repeated in 6th and 7th position).

The simplest idea is probbaly just:

```
ans = 2*elems
random.shuffle(ans)
```

and then some code to take care of the repetitions, but all the solutions I can think of involve potentially infinite loops. Is there a simple and reliable way to do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: You could `shuffle` *then* multiply `random.shuffle(elems); ans = 2*elems`. Or is that insufficiently random?

Comment: Are the elements in the input list distinct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming that the input list has distinct elements.

```
import random

def randomize_carefully(elems, n_repeat=2):
    s = set(elems)
    res = []
    for n in range(n_repeat):
        if res:
            # Avoid the last placed element
            lst = list(s.difference({res[-1]}))
            # Shuffle
            random.shuffle(lst)
            lst.append(res[-1])
            # Shuffle once more to avoid obvious repeating patterns in the last position
            lst[1:] = random.sample(lst[1:], len(lst)-1)
        else:
            lst = elems[:]
            random.shuffle(lst)
        res.extend(lst)
    return res

for i in range(10):
    print randomize_carefully(["A", "B", "C", "D"])
```

Some output:

```
['B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'B']
['B', 'D', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'D']
['C', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A']
['B', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'C']
['D', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']
['C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'A', 'B']
['D', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'D']
['C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']
['C', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'C']
['B', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'B']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a function that checks if two consecutive values in a list `x` are the same:

```
def compareConsecutive(x):
    for i in x:
        if i == x[x.index(i)+1]:
            return False
```

Then shuffle the list in a `while` loop until `compareConsecutive()` stops returning `False`:

```
while compareConsecutive(ans) == False:
    random.shuffle(ans)
```

This could take a while with a long list, since `random.shuffle()` could keep generating lists that have consecutive values in them, but it will work eventually :)

Comment: This might run forever :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be an algorithm for doing what you want:

let `R` be your result list

1. pick a random element `e` from `elems`, and append `e` to `R`
2. let `elems_1 = elems \ e`, i.e. remove `e` from `elems`
3. pick a random element `e_1` from `elems_1`, and append `e_1` to `R`
4. let `elems_1 = elems \ e_1`, i.e. remove `e_1` from `elems`
5. repeat from step 3 until `R` is long enough

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work, although it is not so elegant.

```
import random

elems = ['a','b','c','d']
length = len(elems)

l = []

for i in range(2):
    random.shuffle(elems)
    l.extend( elems )
    if i > 0 and l[ i*length ] == l[ i*length - 1 ]:
        l[i*length-2], l[i*length-1] = l[i*length-1], l[i*length-2]

print l
```